# Child component loses its parameters after login

Tags: angular8, adal

I am trying to open the child component directly in the browser with parameters.

But if I am not logged in I lose all the parameters as the adal services replaces it with the token value. So it redirects me to parent page but expected behavior should be redirecting to child page with those parameters.

Eg :

```
https://localhost:44399/admin/snapshot?dealCode=J9MKU&portfolioCompanyName=Avaloq%20Group%20AG&portfolioCompanyId=1050
```

In this if I am not logged in and I enter this url it first checks if I am authenticated or not. If I am then I can properly see the page as expected if I can not then it will lose all the parameters take me to login page and then after successful login it shows the url as

```
https://localhost:44399/admin/snapshot
```

Comment: Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

`https://localhost:44399/admin/snapshot` is the redirect uri you configured on Azure portal. If you want to pass parameters in the redirect uri, you can add the parameters to the redirect uri. Then you will be redirect to `https://localhost:44399/admin/snapshot?dealCode=J9MKU` after successful login.

[image]

**Note:**

> Azure AD applications can now register and use redirect (reply) URIs
>   with static query parameters (such as
>   https://contoso.com/oauth2?idp=microsoft) for OAuth 2.0 requests.
>   Dynamic redirect URIs are still forbidden as they represent a security
>   risk, and this cannot be used to retain state information across an
>   authentication request - for that, use the state parameter.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-breaking-changes#redirect-uris-can-now-contain-query-string-parameters